# Getting the address of the cell a function has been typed into

Tags: vba, excel, cell, udf

I have been unable to figure this out, and googling has yielded no help!

I have a VBA function which I would like to run in individual cells in a spreadsheet.

The function needs to know the row the function was just typed into.

I currently pass this information by having a column dedicated to row count (ie. it goes 1-2-3-4-5-6-etc.).

This is a bit clumsy and not particularly slick, so I was trying to find a way to basically just type the function (ie. `=myfunc()`) into the cell and then have a line within the cell that does something along the lines of:

```
CurrentRow = CellFunctionWasTypedInto.Row
```

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_Change` event and test to see if your formula was entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Application.ThisCell` object in your function which gives you information about from which cell your formula is called (e.g. `Application.ThisCell.Row`). Similar is `Application.Caller` which is applicable for cell arrays.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969.aspx

Comment: A new thing learnt - knew about `Caller`, but haven't seen `ThisCell`.  Looks like it's been there since at least 2003 as well. :)

Comment: Yes, `ThisCell` is since 2003.